# Wordpress delete posts not in specific categories using wpdb query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

How do I modify the following query to delete all posts with the custom post type "listings" that are NOT IN specific Wordpress categories?

Note, I must use `$wpdb->query()` in my particular situation.
My categories for exclusion are term ID's 21, 22, and 24.

```
$wpdb->query('DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "listings"');
```

UPDATE - THIS query brings me a lot closer to what I am after but throws a SQL error.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts a 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) 
WHERE a.post_type = "listings" 
AND e.term_id NOT IN (21,22,24);
```

Error:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id' at line 1 for query DELETE FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "listings" AND wp_terms.term_id NOT IN (21,22,24)
```

Comment: `AND column_name NOT IN(21, 22, 24)` would have been my first attempt at a solution. What was yours

Comment: The categories in Wordpress are not in the same table schema, hence the problem so simply doing a standard NOT IN in SQL against the wp_posts table will not work.

Comment: Then I would attempt to do a JOIN with the other table, did you attempt anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$wpdb->query('DELETE wp_posts FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "listings" AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy NOT IN (taxonomy_1_slug, taxonomy_2_slug, etc.)');
```

Comment: Resulting SQL error -> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_i' at line 1 for query DELETE FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id WHERE post_type = "listings" AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy NOT IN ("event", "events", "tournaments")

Comment: Yes, sorry for this. Updated an answer. Just forgot the specify the table after DELETE statement. And also use wp_posts.post_type in WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Using category id delete post

```
   delete a,b,c,d
    FROM esx_posts a
    LEFT JOIN esx_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
    LEFT JOIN esx_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
    LEFT JOIN esx_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
    LEFT JOIN esx_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
    WHERE e.term_id = 48
```